# Convert GeoJson to mapbox Polygon object (Android)

Tags: java, android, gson, mapbox

I have a json response from server that contains a Polygon info in GeoJson format, like this :

```
{
"status": "success",
"location": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            50.83657264709473,
                            35.602881307254144
                        ],
                        [
                            50.86541175842285,
                            35.602881307254144
                        ],
                        [
                            50.86541175842285,
                            35.61676761271693
                        ],
                        [
                            50.83657264709473,
                            35.61676761271693
                        ],
                        [
                            50.83657264709473,
                            35.602881307254144
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
}
```

now i want to convert this json to [mapbox Polygon](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/blob/master/services-geojson/src/main/java/com/mapbox/geojson/Polygon.java), i'm using retrofit with gson converter to receive response from server:

```
@GET("example.com")
    Call<MyResponse> getAll();
```

```
import com.mapbox.geojson.Polygon;
public class MyResponse {
    private String status;
    private Polygon location;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Polygon getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Polygon location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

, but i have this error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at path $.location.coordinates[0][0]
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Please add your retrofit code.

Answer (score 0):

Your server's JSON response structure is not as expected by the Code, hence giving the above error.

As per the POJO class Point ([give here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/blob/c53f4a076eb50cb6df81837b1e9b432f5ab4004f/services-geojson/src/main/java/com/mapbox/geojson/Point.java#L54)) , The structure of JSON response should be like:

```
{
   "status": "success",
   "location": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        { type: "String",
                          coordinates: [50.86541175842285,
                            35.61676761271693]
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
}
```